# Flutter Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker) Error

Tags: android, flutter, imagepicker

I'm trying to use [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) on Windows 10. But when the file selection screen is triggered, I get an error like this:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:292:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      ImagePicker.pickImage (package:image_picker/image_picker.dart:64:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _BolatAktarAppState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:bolataktar_resimyukleme/screens/resimyukleme_main.dart:66:52)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

What could this problem be caused by?

Codes:

```
FloatingActionButton.large(
  child: Icon(Icons.folder, color: Colors.white, size: 45,),
  backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 36, 36, 36),
  onPressed: () async {
    final File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image == null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text("the image is not selected."),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 36, 36, 36),
        ),
      );
      return null;
    }
    else {
      print("else");
      uploadImage("bolat", image);
    }
  },
),
// ....
  void uploadImage(String title, File file) async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse("https://api.imgur.com/3/image"));
    request.fields["title"] = title;
    request.headers["Authorization"] = "";
    var picture = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('image', (await rootBundle.load('assets/testimage.png')).buffer.asUint8List(),
    filename: 'resimyukle.png');
    request.files.add(picture);
    var response = await request.send();
    var responseData = await response.stream.toBytes();
    var result = String.fromCharCodes(responseData);
    print(result);
  }
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

`image_picker` doesn't support Windows only Android, iOS and web.